# How to escape the @ character in XSLT

Tags: xslt, data-binding, xslt-1.0

$binding-path contains something like `Contact!ShowsInterest` which should be converted to `Contact/@ShowsInterest`

This is what i tried so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="bindpath" select="translate($binding-path, '!','/&#x40;')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('{Binding XPath=',$bindpath,'}')"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:variable name="bindpath" select="translate($binding-path, '!','/@')" />
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('{Binding XPath=',$bindpath,'}')"/>
```

But no matter what i try, the result is always `Contact/ShowsInterest`

Comment: `translate` only does one-for-one replacements, you can't replace a single character with a two-character string.  You'll have to extract the `substring-before` and `substring-after` the ! and insert the `/@` in between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The [`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) function can only replace every occurence of a single characterwith a single character** (or with nothing, thus deleting it).

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="binding-path" select="'Contact!ShowsInterest'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="bindingpath">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($binding-path, '!')"/>
   <xsl:text>/@</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($binding-path, '!')"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:value-of select="$bindingpath"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Contact/@ShowsInterest
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0**

**Use the XPath 2.0 [`replace()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace) function**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="binding-path" select="'Contact!ShowsInterest'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="bindingpath" select="replace($binding-path, '!', '/@')"/>

  <xsl:value-of select="$bindingpath"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This transformation produces the same correct result:**

```
Contact/@ShowsInterest
```